# Disable sound in specific program

Tags: sound, xubuntu, music

I have a program which plays sound. That program doens't have "disable sound" option. How can I manage sound of programs from ubuntu (or Linux) itself?

I don't want to decrease whole device sound 'cause I want to play music.

I use xubuntu (if helps).

Comment: `pavucontrol` (pulse audio volume control) lets you proportion most applications sound, or individually mute specific ones.  It's not perfect, but is my default go-to for that sort of thing (some programs rely on the OS playing event sounds - so they aren't individually controllable as play as part of system-sounds...Depending on your version of Xubuntu - there is a great pavucontrol plugin for your panel from 18.04 up (which gets better! as you move to later versions as they add more features).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `pavucontrol`  (*Pulse Audio Volume Control*) which lets you individually set volumes of programs, or mute them.  It's not perfect, as some programs use system-sound calls to play audio effects (eg. I nearly always have `hexchat` running, but I can't control it's volume except via system-sounds volume which is fine too).

[image: pavucontrol window shot my Xubuntu 18.04 LTS]

My screenshot is of `pavucontrol` on my Xubuntu 18.04 LTS box, with `audacious` playing music (*hence blue bar showing volume*), `ambient-noise` playing sounds (*currently louder than audacious*) & `vlc` (*paused so silent*).  You'll note a volume-X button to the right of each, which lets you MUTE those sound tracks. To adjust the volume of `hexchat` I'd adjust the slider for system-sounds.

If using 18.04 LTS or later, I'd also suggest adding the PulseAudio Panel Plugin to your panel, as it allows pausing/playing/next/previous for your running audio programs, plus quick access to the Audio-Mixer (or the `pavucontrol` I've provided a picture of). The panel plugin has even better features if you're running 18.10 or later.

Comment: it doesn't work for me